# How can I create user profile after registering user in django using Signals?

Tags: python, django, django-models, signals

I am trying to create userprofile after user has been registered in django app.
User creation is working fine but it is not profile models in admin page.

It is not showing any errors.

So far I have done this.

> users/signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#reciever
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

> users/app.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

> users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pic')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Comment: Please consider using a custom user model instead of a separate profile model, it'll probably make your life easier.

Comment: default_app_config = 'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'
 Put this inside your apps init.py file

Comment: or try importing the signal after the model definition

Comment: after model defination ??do you want me to put signal and models both in same file.

Comment: @MohitHarshan Thanks this worked changeing init file.

Comment: @MohitHarshan but now the problem is i am unable to login to the admin page using my admin user id and password. it says RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/
User has no profile.

Comment: just delete your database ,create new superuser,users,and run again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line of code to your app's `__init__.py` file as [@Mohit Harshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9312327/mohit-harshan) mentioned

```
default_app_config = 'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

**Why `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error?**
Some of your **`User`** object has no ***active*** relation with **`Profile`** instance.So run the following code in your Django shell

```
users_without_profile = User.objects.filter(profile__isnull=True)
for user in users_without_profile:
    Profile.objects.create(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py you should change installed apps

if your settings like this

> `INSTALLED_APPS = ['users']`

you should change it below like this.

> `INSTALLED_APPS = ['users.apps.UsersConfig']`