# Django ImageField Default Image

Tags: html, django, sqlite, django-models, imagefield

In my project I want to allow users to upload profile picture. I am using imagefield but the default option is not working and hence I am getting an error.

```
**models.py**

class Profile_Pic(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,default='images/logo.png',upload_to='images')

@property
def default(self):
    if self.profile_pic:
        return self.profile_pic.url
    else:
        return 'logo.png'
class Meta:
    db_table = 'Profile_Pic'

**views.py**

@login_required
def profile(request):
user = request.user.profile_pic
form = Photo(instance=user)
context = {'photo': form}
return render(request, 'datas/profile.html', context)

**settings.py**

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'admin_car/static/media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'admin_car/static/images')
]

**profile.html**

<div style="text-align: left;position:absolute;top:50px;left:16px;float: left">
       <img class="image" src='{{ user.profile_pic.profile_pic.url }}' style=" height: 200px; width: 200px"  alt="logo.png">
       <style>
    img {
     border-radius: 50%;
        }
    </style>
```

Is there any way where I can add a default picture whenever a new user is created? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you look at signals in django like ` post_save or pre_save`   
            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943171/how-can-i-create-user-profile-after-registering-user-in-django-using-signals

Comment: Any easy example to use signals? I am totally new to django.